# List view click automation using calabash in Android

Tags: android, calabash

I need to automate list item click on Android app. I have googled a lot and not found any useful information. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
Then I press list item number 2
```

Is a predefined Step Definition in Calabash. Using this steps is not best practice [see here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/02-Predefined-steps) for one reason because it´s not written in your business language.

It´s a much better approach if you´re writing your own steps by simply using the according Calabash commands. Due to the fact that Calabash is open source you can find the implementaion of all steps in Github, in your case:

```
Then /^I press list item number (\d+)$/ do |line_index|
  performAction('press_list_item', line_index, 0)
end
```

from [Calabash Repo](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/3ee2a750c1bc6c35c3bedf419fdf73b279af1d8c/ruby-gem/lib/calabash-android/steps/press_button_steps.rb)

Answer (score 0):

You can select list index like this

```
Then I press list item number 2
```

Where 2 is the index in the list you want to select.

Comment: @Lizz That's a calabash.feature syntax. That's how you write a feature to work in calabash. so the above syntax is standard pattern to select an item in the listview